# Writing a file using two different texts as input in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, fasta

I have two big .fasta files that look like this:

File 1:

```
>A01
ABCDGENG
>A02
JALSKDLAS
#and so on
```

File 2:

```
>KJ01
KGLW
>XB02
CTRIPIO
#and so on
```

And I want to generate individual files for each pair of entries (both share the same length, so i.e the first output would look like this:

```
>A01
ABCDGENG
>KJ01
KGLW
```

And, as a detail, they are named after the first file, so the example would be called `A01.fasta`.

I already have a script that works great for when I have only one big file, but I need some guidance on how to add the second part to each individual file.
Here's the script:

```
import os
from os import path
import sys

infile=open("D:/path_to_file")
os.system("D:/path_to_project") # Add your project directory in here

path = "D:/path_to_project"

opened = False # Assume outfile is not open
i=0
for line_ref in infile:
    if line_ref[0] == ">": # If line begins with ">"
        i =i+1 #in case that there are files with the same name
        if(opened): 
            outfile.close() # Will close the outfile if it is open 
        opened = True # Set opened to True to represent an opened outfile
        contig_name = line_ref[1:].rstrip() #Extract contig name: remove ">", extract contig string, remove any spaces or new lins following file
        print("contig: " + contig_name)
        outfile=open(path + "/" + str(contig_name) +"-"+ str(i)+ ".fasta", 'w')
    outfile.write(line_ref)    
outfile.close()
print("Fin")
```

But I don't know how to also go through the lines of the other file (`File 2`) and add them under the first one, without closing the file and opening it again.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suggest you use a library for processing the fasta files instead of reading them directly.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/fasta/

Comment: I thought about using them (there's also pyfastx) but none of them seems to have a built-in function that would help.

Comment: If they have a function that returns a list of all the entries, you just use `zip()` to process them in pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this with normal file operations will be complicated, since FASTA sequences can be a variable number of lines. It's best to use a library to parse the files, such as [pyfastx](https://pypi.org/project/pyfastx/)

```
import pyfastx

fa1 = pyfastx.Fastx('file1.fasta')
fa2 = pyrastx.Fastx('file2.fasta')

for index, ((name1, seq1, comment1), (name2, seq2, comment2)) in enumerate(zip(fa1, fa2), 1):
    with open(f"outfile{index}.fasta", "w") as out:
        out.write(f">{name1}\n{seq1}\n{name2}\n{seq2}\n")
```

Comment: With a couple of tweaks it worked perfectly. Thanks a lot!